# How to make a player jump on an object in java without velocity

Tags: java, animation, collision

My problem is that I want to make my character (Player) jump on objects which I will add later. I was thinking that Tile Collision would work but I don't understand the aspect of it. Besides my game is just one level at a time, not one whole game.

Here is what I have so far. (I didn't write the code to make The Player to jump on anything because I have no idea where to start):

Game.java:

```
public class Game extends gameLoop{

    public void init()
    {
        setSize(854,480);
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(854, 480);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
        addKeyListener(this);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        d.clearRect(0, 0, 854, 480);
        d.drawImage(background, 0 , 0 , this);
        d.drawImage(Player, x, y, this);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0 , 0, this);    
    }
    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

gameLoop.java:

```
public class gameLoop extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    public int x ,y;
    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;
    public boolean up, down, left, right;
    public BufferedImage background, run1, run2, run3, run4, run5, run6, run7, run8, runL1, runL2, runL3, runL4, runL5, stand, Player;
    public int counter;
    public int counterLeft;
    public double counter2 = 4; 


    public void run(){
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("background2.png"));
            stand = ImageIO.read(new File("stick.gif"));
            run1 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner.png"));
            run2 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner1.png"));
            run3 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner2.png"));
            run4 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner3.png"));
            run5 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner4.png"));
            runL1 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner(1).png"));
            runL2 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner1(1).png"));
            runL3 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner2(1).png"));
            runL4 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner3(1).png"));
            runL5 = ImageIO.read(new File("Runner4(1).png"));

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Player = stand;
        while(true){
            if(y <= 319 && up != true){
                y+=10;
            }



            counter++;
            counterLeft ++;
            if (counter >= 90){
                counter = 0;
            }
            if (counter >= 10 &&  right == true && left == false){
                Player = run1;
            }
            if (counter >= 20 &&  right == true && left == false){
                Player = run2;
            }
            if (counter >= 30 &&  right == true && left == false){
                Player = run3;
            }
            if (counter >= 40 &&  right == true && left == false){
                Player = run4;
            }
            if (counter >= 50 &&   right == true && left == false){
                Player = run5;
            }
            if (counter >= 60 &&  right == true && left == false){
                Player = run1;
            }
            if (counter >= 70 &&  right == true && left == false){
                Player = run2;
            }
            if(counter >= 80 && right == true && left == false){
                Player = run3;
            }

            // LEFT
            if (counterLeft >= 55){
                counterLeft = 0;
            }
            if (counterLeft >= 10 &&  left == true && right == false){
                Player = runL1;
            }
            if (counterLeft >= 20 &&  left == true && right == false){
                Player = runL2;
            }
            if (counterLeft >= 30 && left == true && right == false){
                Player = runL3;
             }
            if (counterLeft >= 40 && left == true && right == false){
                Player = runL4;
            }
            if (counterLeft >= 50 && left == true && right == false){
                Player = runL5;
            }




            if (left == true){
                x--;
            }
            if (right == true){
                x++;
            }

            if (up == true){
                counter2 += 0.05;
                y = y + (int) ((Math.sin(counter2) + Math.cos(counter2))* 5);
                if(counter2 >= 7){
                    counter2 = 4;

                }
            }
            if(down == true){
                y++;
            }
            if(y >= 319){
                y = 319;
            }


            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        }



    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37 && e.getKeyCode() != 38){ //left
            left = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 38 && e.getKeyCode() != 37){ //up or jump
            up = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39){ //right
            right = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40){ //down
            down = true;
        }

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37){  
            left = false;
            Player = stand;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up = false;
            Player = stand;

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right = false;
            Player = stand;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down = false;
            Player = stand;
        }
    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

So far all he can do is run and jump.

Comment: Don't use `Applet`, consider using `JApplet`, in fact, base the core graphics on a `JPanel`, then you can add to either a `JApplet`, `JFrame` or other container.  Applet's won't have access to the file system when they are deployed either

Comment: Would that work with BlueJ? Because righ now I'm using eclipse but I need to show my teacher in school with BlueJ.

Comment: Two things worth investing in as I see it 1) KeyBindings and 2) a Swing Timer. P.S. "right == true && left == false" is excessively redundant in your code... If nothing else it "should" be `right && !left`.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't help me with my problem. I don't understand how I can make the Player jump onto a something.

Comment: I clearly don't understand how I Can use Tile Collision if my code has nothing to do with TileMap. Anything else I Can use besides Tile Collision or any for of Collision. I know something has to Collide with the player as soon as it hits a surface/platform., but I don't know how I can do that. Completely Lost here.

Comment: That may be but you should be open to suggestions. IMHO, it's sort of putting the cart before the horse trying to handle game collisions while not really getting more simple stuff. That being said an object, say a box, has a top and a player has feet (their bottom). How would you go about determining if the player was atop this box? It's really simple actually. When the player's bottom y value is <= the box's top y value you have a collision and now you have to resolve it. You can google game collisions and find soooo many coded examples in many languages.

Comment: Okay, I will look into it. Thanks, but keep the suggestions coming I can use any help I can get right now.